# React Native re-mount screen

Tags: react-native, mount, react-navigation

On my first page I have a list, which I get with a fetch. This works on the first call. But when I go to an other screen with `this.props.navigation.navigate('OtherScreen');` and return to the old screen with

```
 const backAction = NavigationActions.back({
     key: null,
 });
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction)
```

my list won't get refreshed, because of the `componentDidMount` method where I call the fetch won't get triggered again. I've also tried `componentWillUpdate`, but this won't get triggered again as well.

How can I force the screen to re-mount, when i enter it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate.

Or, if I correctly understood the task

```
//screen A
import {DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native'
componentWillMount() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('your listener', (e)=>{})
}

//screenB
DeviveEventEmitter.emit('your listener',  {})
```

Comment: I know this is old but `componentWillMount` is deprecated and unsafe to use

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how DeviceEventEmitter works in this situation, but i made it like this:

Screen A:

```
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     images: [],
   };
 }

  onPressCamera() {
   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

   navigate('CameraScreen', {
     refreshImages: function (data) {
       this.setState({images: this.state.images.concat(data)});
     }.bind(this),
   });
}

render
...
<FlatList
  data={ this.state.images }
  renderItem={ (row) => this.renderImage(row) }
  keyExtractor={ item => item.path }
/>
```

Screen B:

```
  takePicture() {
   const {params = {}} = this.props.navigation.state;

  this.camera.capture()
     .then((data) => {
       params.refreshImages([data]);
     })
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

Here I navigated to camera screen and then clicked capture button I refreshing prev screen.

Answer (score 0):

i use **NavigationEvents** to refresh screens after they got mounted, i use it like the following :

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
```

then just call it  :

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <NavigationEvents
                onDidFocus={() => Alert.alert('Refreshed')}
                />
                <Button
                onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Other_Screen')}}
            />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

This will refresh your screens in each navigation. hope it's what you're looking for!